# VS Code doesn't install extension 'VIBRANCY', shows 'Your Code installation appears to be corrupt. Please reinstall.'

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

When I try to install vibrancy extension and reload it, it first shows:

> "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'g:\Softwares
> Install\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vscode-vibrancy-runtime-v6''

Then I run VS as admin still it shows "Your Code installation appears to be corrupt. Please reinstall." When I try to reload the extension.

I tried uninstalling VS but nothing works. This extension was working fine few days ago but now it's giving error.
How can I fix this issue?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: *This extension works by editting VS Code's css file. So, a prompt will appear when installing vscode-vibrancy for the first time or each time VS Code updates. U can click [never show again] to hide it.* from the readme: https://github.com/EYHN/vscode-vibrancy

Answer (score 1):

The Vibrancy extension said itself in their description that the "your code is corrupted" error popup is normal since it alters VsCode's css files but you can just press the gear button and make it not show up again.

However, I dont know anything abt the first error so sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

solve the error in the following way
you have to go to P:\VS-CODE-CODE-resources-appout-vibrancy-vibrancy-runtime-v6 and delete the files that are inside with VSCODE closed then you go to settings and put -1 and it will ask you to reboot and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I used `Fix VSCode Checksum` to solved this problem:
[Usage](https://github.com/Lin-jun-xiang/vscode-extensions-best#wrenchfixer-fix-vscode-corrupt)